How to solve python numpy error while executiong code
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

url = "https://web.archive.org/web/20230902185326/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_GDP_%28nominal%29"
tables = pd.read_html(url)
df = tables[3]
print(df)

i have executed this code in vscode and both pandas and numpy are already installed and even though the code is not working and i am getting the following error
File "c:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\Python\lab.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from pandas.compat import (
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from pandas.compat.numpy import is_numpy_dev
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\numpy\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    _np_version = np.__version__
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute '__version__'

I tried by uninstalling and installing pandas and numpy but there was no use it still gives the same error

Try uninstalling and reinstalling numpy:
pip uninstall -y numpy
pip uninstall -y setuptools
pip install setuptools
pip install numpy

Answer based on this link.
